# Add buttons above the image in a particular position in android

Tags: android, xml

[image]

I want to add buttons above each numbers. I did by placing buttons above the number place, but when I run it in other resolution mobile the buttons are not at its position. May be due to image expansion in other high resolution mobile it is happening.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image1"

tools:context="com.homescreenapp.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5" >

</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/twleve" />
```

Comment: why not make the text clickable ?

Comment: Bcause I'm passing intent to that button

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny either way both are same button or textview. in other resolution mobile button/textview wont be in particular position.

Comment: I don't understand your reason what do you mean you passing intent to that button

Comment: ok that's how android support different resolution work you need to add different layouts , dimensions and resources for different screens you can't make one screen for them all

Comment: I want to place a button on that image where in the image it is showing "No.1" place. Passing intent is next step. i just want to place a button on that place.

Comment: that means i just need to add different resolution images to drawable folder?

Comment: yes in addition too different dimensions and layouts and may I suggest you take a look in the documentations http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i added different dimension images to drawable folders but stil its not coming.

Comment: different dimensions means if margin left in a small screen is 50dp in a larger screen it should be 70dp

Comment: ya.. but in your case button wil change its position but background image wont.

Comment: that is why you provide not only different dimensions but also different images and different layouts and may I suggest that this kind of implementation is  poor where you want a background and you want to adjust your buttons to it

Comment: @Kirataka, while asking question, try to provide enough informations about your exact scenario. Here, you have mentioned that  above "No1" image , u have placed a button. Then provide only that part of image and mention which image & button your r refering to. And "passing intent to that button" is not clear.

Comment: @sowmia try to understand first.. i already told that intent comes in next step. & i'm not asking about intent here. that "Numer1" image is i mentioned here is the place where which i want to add button in that place. Actually i tried to clear my question there.

Comment: @AhmedBasyouny that meas u try to say using different layouts for different places?

Comment: yes a layout for mobile , one for tab 7 and one for tab 10